# Multi Factor Authentication / SignIn with multiple providers in parallel

Tags: next-auth

Is it possible to allow the user to sign in to two different providers at the same time? I would like for example for a user to sign in with Google then for example sign in with Facebook (while being signed in to Google) and be able to manipulate session/scope/permissions/userData of both at the same time.

Any guidance would be of great help!

I tried digging into the docs but couldn't find anything relevant so far